# Report Viewer C# data from MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, report, reportviewer

I am using Report Viewer with C# Asp.Net and MySQL. But MySQL doesn't appear like option at Data Source from Report Data.

[image: example]

The MySQL is not a database option.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Download the complete version of MySQL installer that has about 378 Mb - [Download here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/)
2. Install it.
3. Go to Add --> Applications --> MySQL for Visual Studio and click in the arrow to add it at a list to be added. Do the same with MySQL Connectors --> Connector/Net.
4. Click in next.
5. Click em execute.
6. After that close and open your Visual Studio.

> The problem was the web installer. For some reason the version of MySQL connector and MySQL for Visual Studio was not working with Visual Studio 2015. Hope help it. [Problem solved.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mr80E.png)